# 27 squares of side $1$ inside a circle of radius $2$: Show that three squares share an interior point.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, circles, pigeonhole-principle

> By placing 27 squares with side $1$ in a circle with radius $2$, such that each square is entirely inside the circle, prove that there exists a point that 3 squares share (inside of their area).

I thought about dividing the circle into 9 equal areas and using the pigeonhole principle, but got stuck there. Any hint will help.

Comment: Well, what should I assign it to?
It is a question I got at my  combinatorics course.

Comment: @idk Ok, thank you! didn't know about that tag.

Comment: It belongs to correct tag just add the tag "Pigeonhole principle "

Comment: @Manthanein thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the desired conclusion, $26$ unit squares will suffice.

Let $D$ denote the disk of radius $2$, and let $C$ be the subregion of $D$ covered by some placement of $26$ unit squares within $D$.

Suppose every point of $D$ is contained in at most two of the unit squares.

Our  goal is to derive a contradiction.

Let $X_i$ denote the $i$-th unit square.

For each $i$, let

- $A_i$ be the subset of $X_i$ which does not intersect any of the other squares.$\\[4pt]$

  $B_i = X_i{\setminus}A_i$.

For a given set $S$, let $[S]$ denote the area of $S$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;
4\pi&=[D]\\[4pt]
&\ge [C]\\[4pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^{26}[A_i] + \left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right) \sum_{i=1}^{26}[B_i]\\[4pt]
&\ge \left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right) \sum_{i=1}^{26}[A_i] + \left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right) \sum_{i=1}^{26}[B_i]\\[4pt]
&= \left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right) \sum_{i=1}^{26}\left([A_i] + [B_i]\right)\\[4pt]
&= \left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right) \sum_{i=1}^{26}\,(1)\\[4pt]
&= \left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)(26)\\[4pt]
&= 13\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
contradiction.

This proves the claim.

**Note:**

Squares are an awkward shape for covering a large subregion of a disk, so I suspect the actual maximum number of unit squares which can be placed in a disk of radius $2$, such that each point of the disk is covered by at most two of the unit squares, is a lot less than $25$.

Comment: Such an elegant solution!
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Lets denote by $A$ the area that the squares occupy.

Of course $A\leq4\pi$(the area of the circle). Let's also suppose that there are no 3 squares that share a point.

Therefor only $2$ squares can intersect, i.e. $A>\frac{27}{2}$, so $$8\pi>27$$ which is false

Comment: Shouldn't ie be $14$ instead of $27/2$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust $14>27/2$ so it works even better, doesn't really matter in my opinion

Comment: How did you get to these numbers ?

Comment: @Eliads What numbers

Comment: @razvanelda $A > 27/2$ and $14$

Comment: @Eliads I didn't say anything about $14$ and $A>27/2$ from the fact that maximum 2 squares can intersect

Comment: @razvanelda Yes I understand , but why $27/2$ exactly?

Comment: @Eliads Because in the worst case $13$ squares would overlay with another $13$ and one will be separate, so $A=14$, I just said $27/2$ because I thought it would be more clear

Comment: @razvanelda Oh, I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Eliads No problem!

Answer (score 0):

@razvanelda: With your reasoning wouldn’t 26 squares be sufficient in order to force 3 squares to have a common interior point since $8\pi>26$ is also false?

Comment: Yes it would  be, so?...